Can't mount anything on a rooted android device: not in /proc/mounts
I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S23 with Android 14 and Magisk 27 installed.
I ran adb root successfully and then proceeded to go into adb shell in which I obviously had root rights (#).
Then I ran mount -o remount,rw /data/adb/service.d which gave me the error message mount: '/service.d' not in /proc/mounts.
This always occurs whenever I try to mount/remount any root directory.
How can this be fixed?

Self-related: adb can't remount - Magisk on an Android 14 Samsung device
